# external configuration file for enterprise library

Tags: c#, configuration, enterprise-library, external

If i use an external configuration file for [Microsoft enterprise library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx) for my program,  then all the configuration for enterprise library must reside in the external configuration file? can i still have part of the configuration in the hosting configuration file?

Comment: What is an "enterprise library"? What programming language, framework, servers, etc. do you use?

Comment: @lutz - http://www.codeplex.com/entlib

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to configure Entlib in an external file, and override some settings on your app.config?

If that's the case, check the EntLib [Hands-On Labs](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Hands-on%20Labs&referringTitle=Home). Particularly take a look at the configuration HOL; it shows you how to inherit configuration from a shared location, and override it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Enterprise Library 5.0

I needed to reference my enterprise library config outside the app.config.

I used the following with my own logging factory:

```
var configSource = new FileConfigurationSource("EntiLib.config");
var logWriterFactory = new LogWriterFactory(configSource);
var logWriter = logWriterFactory.Create();
```

I was able to find this solution on CodePlex
[answer on code plex](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/233579?ProjectName=entlib)

Answer (score 1):

Good links by Nicolas and Peter. Glad you found the hands-on labs useful. In addition, please take a look at [this chapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953193%28PandP.50%29.aspx) that we wrote to explain various configuration scenarios, including:

- reading configuration information from a wide range of sources.
- enforcing common configuration settings across multiple applications.
- sharing configuration settings between applications.
- specifying a core set of configuration settings that applications can inherit.
- merging configuration settings that are stored in a shared location.
- creating different configurations for different deployment environments.